# Is a vote to close considered a "helpful flag"?

Tags: discussion, badges

I thought I had a whole lot of votes-to-close, so I'm wondering if they count as helpful flags or if I just have fewer than I thought I did.

Comment: @Glorfindel Are you saying... From the review queue to handle VLQ and NAA flags, a user should _flag the answers they review_ as VLQ or NAA? That sounds like a blatant misuse of the review system in my mind.

Comment: You could search for and flag VLQ and NAA answers. There are myriads to be found...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Close votes don't count as flags.  Since you have the [3k close votes privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you cast a close vote *instead of* a flag when closing questions.  So you won't be able submit any flags by closing questions.

Instead, you'll have to submit other kinds of flags.  Your remaining options are:

- spam
- offensive
- very low quality
- not an answer
- custom (in need of moderator attention)
- [any comment flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

Just make sure your flags are, you know, helpful.  Alternatively, you could donate your reputation until getting under 3k so you lose the close votes privilege.  Then your close votes become flags again, but that would mean you wouldn't qualify for the moderator position due to this cycle's reputation requirement of 3k.

Comment: Doesn't it seem weird? Same situation for example `edit`, when you have enough reputation to enter the `edit` review queue, you can still make countable edit for your privilege. But for `flag`, it comes to be a lot harder if the `close` not countable for it.